# Check if member exists?

Tags: python, discord

I'm trying to see if a member exists in a Discord server. So far, I have:

```
@bot.command()
async def profile(ctx, member:discord.Member = None):
    if member is None:
        print("Member not specified")
    else:
        #I want to check if member exists
        print("Member specified")
```

It's recognizing that I have passed an arg, however if that member doesn't exist (@testing), it's throwing:

> discord.ext.commands.errors.BadArgument: Member "@testing" not found

How do I check to see if a member exists in the server? I'd like to send a message if it's not the case.
Thanks

Comment: Can you please include the code where the error is thrown?

Comment: That's the code ^

Comment: Can you provide the full error traceback